# Como emplear un ng-model con array

Tags: angularjs

Este es mi código http://plnkr.co/edit/oxtojjEPwkKng9iKkc14?p=preview

Quiero guardar uno o varios objetos en un array, tengo dos selects con las mismas opciones, el usuario decide si llenar la opción por defecto o llenar varias,

Debería guardarse de la siguiente manera:

```
likes[
  {sport: 'futball', points: 1}, {sport: 'tennis', points: 1}
]
```

pero como podría guardar los datos en un array en el ng-model de cada select?

porque quiero utilizar algo así como `ng-model="array[$index].sport"` o `.point`

no sé si sea posible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma es crear un array en tu controller.

```
$scope.coleccion = [] ;
```

Luego en el HTML pones algo así `ng-model="coleccion[0].deporte"`

Ejemplo:

```
<selectize placeholder='Pick some things...' options='myOptions' 
           config="{maxItems: 1}" ng-model="coleccion[0].deporte" 
           required='true'></selectize>

<input type="number" min="1" ng-model="coleccion[0].puntuacion" required>
```

Este es tu ejemplo con los cambios aplicados...

http://plnkr.co/edit/Va9wVojeoLWEtpcazfIP?p=preview

Recuerda presionar "save" para ver como queda el resultado.

Comment: Hay alguna forma de colocar la posición dinámica? porque en caso de que sean más de dos opciones, y lo quiera hacer con ng-repeat?

Comment: entiendo, por que no editas la pregunta y explicas eso, asi con todo el panorama se bien como responderte.

Answer (score 0):

si el ng-model esta dentro de un `ng-repeat` :

> Controlador > `$scope.likes = [];`
>
> Vista > `ng-model="likes[$index]['sport']"`

eso te va a funcionar bien.

intentalo primero, al parecer aun no pruebas con lo que tu mismo dices.